# Check localstorage value and pass parameters at state.go in IONIC

Tags: php, android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have create an ionic app that will set the token value whenever a successful login is made by the user. Then, it will make use of $state.go to redirect the user to another tab "tab.scan".

When user clicked on the "tab.details" tab at the navigation bar, it will redirect the user to "tab.details" without passing any parameters.

However, the "details" page did not manage to get the value of the stored token.
How can I go about doing it?

It works fine when the url is `url: '/details'` instead of `url: '/details/:store_id/:invoice_id'`.

Code for login

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, LoginService, $ionicPopup, $state, $stateParams) {
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.token = { token: "" };

    $scope.login = function () {
        LoginService.loginUser($scope.data.username, $scope.data.password).success(function (data) {
            //Set login token
            localStorage.setItem("token", $scope.data.username);
            //Redirect the user to scan tab
            $state.go('tab.scan', { store_id: $scope.data.store_id });
            //Popup alert for welcome message
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Login Success!',
                template: 'Welcome ' + localStorage.getItem("token") + '!'
            });
        }).error(function (data) {
            //Failed login, popup error message
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Login Failed!',
                template: 'Please check your credentials!'
            });
        });
    }
})
```

Code for tabs

```
.state('tab.details', {
      cache: false,
      url: '/details/:store_id/:invoice_id',
      views: {
        'tab-details': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-details.php',
          controller: 'DetailsCtrl'
        }
  }
})
```

Code for detail controller

```
.controller('DetailsController', function ($scope, $http, $state, $ionicPopup, $stateParams) {
    $scope.token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    console.log($scope.token);
    if ($scope.token == "logOut") {
        $state.go('login');
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Login Required!',
            template: 'Please login to access.'
        });
    }
    else {
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

$scope is relative to each controller unless login is a parent state $scope will not cascade to child states. You need to set token in  a service which can be called from any controller or you can set it on $rootScope so it is available everywhere. Is you want to use $rootScope change $scope.token to $rootScope.token.